# How can I handle non-text messages with Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I'm building a chatbot with Facebook Messenger and Google Dialogflow. In messenger there is a commonly used sticker (a big blue thumbs up) which is basically a picture. For now the chatbot cant recognize the stickers url or id. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here is to transform the receiving of a sticker in whatever your middleman API is that connects Facebook Messenger to Dialogflow. This echoes the pattern many Phone IVRs do when a user presses a button - it simply transforms that input into text such as `DTMF Zero` to hand to the detect intent request. You could similarly transform sending a sticker as `Sticker` and use that as your training phrase.